# Rails: How to use i18n with Rails 4 enums

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, enums

Rails 4 [Active Record Enums](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#active-record-enums) are great, but what is the right pattern for translating with i18n?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I didn't find any specific pattern either, so I simply added:

```
en:
  user_status:
    active:   Active
    pending:  Pending...
    archived: Archived
```

to an arbitrary .yml file. Then in my views:

```
I18n.t :"user_status.#{user.status}"
```

Comment: i did something similar, but i put it under `{locale}.activerecord.attributes.{model}.{attribute}`and wrote a `t_enum(model, enum, value)` helper method so the enum translations would be adjacent to the label translation

Answer (score 94):

Starting from Rails 5, all models will inherit from `ApplicationRecord`.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  enum status: [:active, :pending, :archived]
end
```

I use this superclass to implement a generic solution for translating enums:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  def self.human_enum_name(enum_name, enum_value)
    I18n.t("activerecord.attributes.#{model_name.i18n_key}.#{enum_name.to_s.pluralize}.#{enum_value}")
  end
end
```

Then I add the translations in my `.yml` file:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        statuses:
          active: "Active"
          pending: "Pending"
          archived: "Archived"
```

Finally, to get the translation I use:

```
User.human_enum_name(:status, :pending)
=> "Pending"
```

Comment: How would you handle using this in a dropdown (ie when not displaying a single value)?

Comment: @tirdadc you can handle a dropdown like this: `<%= f.select :status, User.statuses.keys.collect { |status| [User.human_enum_name(:status, status), status] } %>`.

Comment: +1 good answer. I tweaked it for my use to be a view helper method since I feel this is more of a view concern, and to not pluralize the attribute name: https://gist.github.com/abevoelker/fed59c2ec908de15acd27965e4725762 Call it in a view like `human_enum_name(@user, :status)`

Comment: Per  Repolês, you could also add another class method to your base model for dropdowns: ```self.human_enum_collection(enum_name)```. Code would be  ```send(enum_name.to_s.pluralize).keys.collect { |val| [human_enum_name(enum_name, val), val] }```

Comment: Usually there is more than one enum name and enum value, does this mean that I have to def ```self.human_enum_name2``` and ```def self.human_enum_name3``` and so on?

Comment: @TPR to use the method `self.human_enum_name` you have to specify the enum name and the enum value. This means only one generic class method will be enough, doesn't matter how many enums your ActiveRecord class has.

Comment: @Repolês I see that the code has only one ```(enum_name, enum_value)```, if I have more than one enum name and enum value, how should I write this without confusion?

Comment: @TPR here's an example: https://gist.github.com/repoles/e798a915a0df49e3bcce0b7932478728. Let me know if you have any question.

Answer (score 36):

To keep the internationalization similar as any other attribute I followed the nested attribute way as you can see [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models).

If you have a class `User`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum role: [ :teacher, :coordinator ]
end
```

And a `yml` like this:

```
pt-BR:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user/role: # You need to nest the values under model_name/attribute_name
        coordinator: Coordenador
        teacher: Professor
```

You can use:

```
User.human_attribute_name("role.#{@user.role}")
```

Comment: This is visually appealing but it breaks the rails convention of `activerecord.attributes.<fieldname>` being the `label` translation for form helpers

Comment: @ChrisBeck it appears this follows the convention described in the Rails I18n Guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models

Comment: In my experience this works without using the `role` key. You can nest `coordinator` and `teacher` directly under `user`.

Comment: what is human_attribute_name?

Answer (score 33):

Here is a view:

```
select_tag :gender, options_for_select(Profile.gender_attributes_for_select)
```

Here is a model (you can move this code into a helper or a decorator actually)

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum gender: {male: 1, female: 2, trans: 3}

  # @return [Array<Array>]
  def self.gender_attributes_for_select
    genders.map do |gender, _|
      [I18n.t("activerecord.attributes.#{model_name.i18n_key}.genders.#{gender}"), gender]
    end
  end
end
```

And here is locale file:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      profile:
        genders:
          male: Male
          female: Female
          trans: Trans
```

Comment: but how to get translation for single record in this case? Because `.human_attribute_name('genders.male')` don't work

Comment: Thank you, works like charm in [my case](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42185293/6873497)!

Comment: I've made lightweight gem for these purposes https://github.com/shlima/translate_enum

Comment: FML - it is 2021 and this still doesn't properly work with simple_form. But - thanks to your comment I have a good workaround :-)

Comment: What is the genders of ```genders.map```? I keep getting ```undefined local variable or method `genders'```

Answer (score 8):

Elaborating on user3647358's answer, you can accomplish that very closely to what you're used to when translating attributes names.

Locale file:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      profile:
        genders:
          male: Male
          female: Female
          trans: Trans
```

Translate by calling I18n#t:

```
profile = Profile.first
I18n.t(profile.gender, scope: [:activerecord, :attributes, :profile, :genders])
```

Comment: This is the minimalist solution only using framework tools and therefore the best one in my eyes. Maybe add a test so that you cover all genders in your translations.

Answer (score 7):

Model:

```
enum stage: { starting: 1, course: 2, ending: 3 }

def self.i18n_stages(hash = {})
  stages.keys.each { |key| hash[I18n.t("checkpoint_stages.#{key}")] = key }
  hash
end
```

Locale:

```
checkpoint_stages:
    starting: Saída
    course: Percurso
    ending: Chegada
```

And on the view (.slim):

```
= f.input_field :stage, collection: Checkpoint.i18n_stages, as: :radio_buttons
```

Answer (score 7):

Combining the answers from [Repolês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36335591/) and [Aliaksandr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23710247/), for Rails 5, we can build 2 methods that allow you to translate a single value or a collection of values from an enum attribute.

Set up the translations in your `.yml` file:

```yml
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        statuses:
          active: "Active"
          pending: "Pending"
          archived: "Archived"
```

In the `ApplicationRecord` class, from which all models inherit, we define a method that handles translations for a single value and another one that handles arrays by calling it:

```rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  def self.translate_enum_name(enum_name, enum_value)
    I18n.t("activerecord.attributes.#{model_name.i18n_key}.#{enum_name.to_s.pluralize}.#{enum_value}")
  end

  def self.translate_enum_collection(enum_name)
    enum_values = self.send(enum_name.to_s.pluralize).keys
    enum_values.map do |enum_value|
      self.translate_enum_name enum_name, enum_value
    end
  end
end
```

In our views, we can then translate single values:

```rb
<p>User Status: <%= User.translate_enum_name :status, @user.status %></p>
```

Or the entire collection of enum values:

```rb
<%= f.select(:status, User.translate_enum_collection :status) %>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me translating enums. There was only one change I needed to do to use it on selects, to put as value the key of the enum and as text the translation, instead of the map in translate_enum_collection:

`enum_values.each_with_object({}) do |enum_value, acc|
   acc[enum_value] = self.translate_enum_name(enum_name, enum_value)
end`

And then in the view add an invert: 

`User.translate_enum_collection(:status).invert`

Answer (score 4):

I've created a gem for this.

http://rubygems.org/gems/translated_attribute_value

Add to your gemfile:

```
gem 'translated_attribute_value'
```

If you have a status field for user:

```
pt-BR:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        status_translation:
          value1: 'Translation for value1'
          value2: 'Translation for value2'
```

And in your view you can call like this:

```
user.status_translated
```

It works with active record, mongoid or any other class with getter/setters:

https://github.com/viniciusoyama/translated_attribute_value

Answer (score 4):

Try using [TranslateEnum](https://github.com/shlima/translate_enum) gem for these purposes

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: { published: 0, archive: 1 }
  translate_enum :status
end


Post.translated_status(:published)
Post.translated_statuses

@post = Post.new(status: :published)
@post.translated_status
```

Comment: We also use this gem. Has the cleanest approach from all options we evaluated and is well maintained.

Answer (score 3):

The model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum role: [:master, :apprentice]
end
```

The locale file:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        master: Master
        apprentice: Apprentice
```

Usage:

```
User.human_attribute_name(:master) # => Master
User.human_attribute_name(:apprentice) # => Apprentice
```

Comment: How about `@user.role`, because that is the main issue.

Comment: The most straight forward, clean and elegant way.

Comment: AnyModel.human_attribute_name(:i_dont_exist) => "I dont exist"

Answer (score 2):

Try the [enum_help](https://github.com/zmbacker/enum_help) gem. From its description:

> Help ActiveRecord::Enum feature to work fine with I18n and simple_form.

Answer (score 2):

Heres a `t_enum` helper method that I use.

```
<%= t_enum(@user, :status) %>
```

*enum_helper.rb*:

```
module EnumHelper

  def t_enum(inst, enum)
    value = inst.send(enum);
    t_enum_class(inst.class, enum, value)
  end

  def t_enum_class(klass, enum, value)
    unless value.blank?
      I18n.t("activerecord.enums.#{klass.to_s.demodulize.underscore}.#{enum}.#{value}")
    end
  end

end
```

*user.rb*:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [:active, :pending, :archived]
end
```

*en.yml*:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    enums:
      user:
        status:
          active:   "Active"
          pending:  "Pending..."
          archived: "Archived"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way, I find it a bit more convenient using a concern in models

Concern :

```
module EnumTranslation
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def t_enum(enum)
    I18n.t "activerecord.attributes.#{self.class.name.underscore}.enums.#{enum}.#{self.send(enum)}"
  end
end
```

YML:

```
fr:
    activerecord:
      attributes:
        campaign:
          title: Titre
          short_description: Description courte
          enums:
            status:
              failed: "Echec"
```

View :

```
<% @campaigns.each do |c| %>
  <%= c.t_enum("status") %>
<% end %>
```

Don't forget to add concern in your model :

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  include EnumTranslation

  enum status: [:designed, :created, :active, :failed, :success]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer a simple helper in application_helper

```
  def translate_enum(object, enum_name)
    I18n.t("activerecord.attributes.#{object.model_name.i18n_key}.#{enum_name.to_s.pluralize}.#{object.send(enum_name)}")
  end
```

Then in my YML file :

```
fr:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      my_model:
        my_enum_plural:
          pending:  "En cours"
          accepted: "Accepté"
          refused:  "Refusé"
```

Answer (score 1):

Model **Order**:

```
 enum order_type: {normal: false, security: true}.freeze, _default: :normal
```

**OrdersController**

```
    @order_type = Order.order_types.except(:security) unless secure_present # optional code
    @order_type.transform_keys! { |key| I18n.t("orders.new.order_types.#{key}")}
```

**Locales** *(Ukrainian)*

```
uk:
  orders:
    new:
      order_types:
        normal: 'Звичайна'
        security: 'Безпечна'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a helper:

```
def my_something_list
  modes = 'activerecord.attributes.mymodel.my_somethings'
  I18n.t(modes).map {|k, v| [v, k]}
end
```

and set it up as usually:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      mymodel:
        my_somethings:
           my_enum_value: "My enum Value!"
```

then use it with your select: `my_something_list`

Answer (score 0):

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  def self.enum(definitions)
    defind_i18n_text(definitions) if definitions.delete(:_human)
    super(definitions)
  end

  def self.defind_i18n_text(definitions)
    scope = i18n_scope
    definitions.each do |name, values|
      next if name.to_s.start_with?('_')
      define_singleton_method("human_#{name.to_s.tableize}") do
        p values
        values.map { |key, _value| [key, I18n.t("#{scope}.enums.#{model_name.i18n_key}.#{name}.#{key}")] }.to_h
      end

      define_method("human_#{name}") do
        I18n.t("#{scope}.enums.#{model_name.i18n_key}.#{name}.#{send(name)}")
      end
    end
  end
end


en:
  activerecord:
    enums:
      mymodel:
        my_somethings:
           my_enum_value: "My enum Value!"

enum status: [:unread, :down], _human: true
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the simplest solution I have found.

Model file 'house.rb':

```
enum status: { unavailable: 0, available: 1 }
```

In the view, a simple_form select:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@house) do |f| %>
...
<%= f.input :status,
        collection: House.statuses.keys.map { |s| [t("house_enum_status_#{s}"), s] }
...
<% end %>
```

The collection creates an array with [key, value] expected for the select, with the correct translation.

And here is both locales yml files used:

'fr.yml'

```
house_enum_status_unavailable: "Indisponible"
house_enum_status_available: "Disponible"
```

'en.yml'

```
house_enum_status_unavailable: "Not available"
house_enum_status_available: "Available"
```

[Here is the result in French](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUW9I.png)

[Here is the result in English](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgelO.png)