# How to write i18n String for Rails 4.1 Enums?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.1

For exmaple, edit config/locales/en.yml

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      user: User
    attributes:
      user:
        name: Name
```

You can get

```
User.model_name.human # => User

User.human_attribute_name('name') # => Name
```

But how to write Rails 4.1 [Enums](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) I18n values ?

Answer (score 2):

Try the [enum_help](https://github.com/zmbacker/enum_help) gem. From its description:

> Help ActiveRecord::Enum feature to work fine with I18n and simple_form.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any specific pattern either, so I simply added:

```
en:
  user_status:
    active:   Active
    pending:  Pending...
    archived: Archived
```

to an arbitrary .yml file. Then in my views:

```
I18n.t :"user_status.#{user.status}"
```

cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23104850/797639