# Translate a value in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, yaml, rails-i18n

I have a model called State and its attribute is name from Type String. There are currently two values I want to assign: "Imported" and "Archived".
After creating a document I set state via controller to "Imported". In the Spanish version it should be called "Importado". In the database it should be "Imported". So I created a locale in document.es.yml

```
# ruby encoding: utf-8
es:
  activerecord:
    models:
      ar/document:
        one:   "Documento"
        other: "Documentos"

    attributes:
      ar/document:
        name:                   "Nombre"
        state:                  "Estado"
        state_id:               "Estado"

        states:
          imported:             "Importado"
          archived:             "Archivado"
```

And state.es.yml

```
# ruby encoding: utf-8
es:
  activerecord:
    models:
      ar/state:
        one:   "Estado"
        other: "Estados"

    attributes:
      ar/state:
        name:                   "Estado"
        imported:               "Importado"
        archived:               "Archivado"
```

In the view the other Spanish locales are loaded. How can I assign a translation to a value and show it in a view?

```
<%= bootstrap_show_for :record => @document do %>
  <%= show_for @document do |document| %>
    <%= document.attribute :name %>
    <%= document.association :state %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Try `t("activerecord.attributes.ar/state.#{document.state}")` or `t("activerecord.attributes.ar/document.states.#{document.state}")`

Comment: The ActiveRecord I18n Model attribute keys are not really meant to be used this way. They are meant to translate property names - not their values. Also if you have a limited set of states for a property you should use [an enum](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/creating-easy-readable-attributes-with-activerecord-enums/) for performance instead of a string. You can use the tricks listed here for translation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827270/how-to-use-i18n-with-rails-4-enums

Comment: So I switched the line to `<%= document.association :state, t("activerecord.attributes.ar/state.#{document.state.name}") %>` and get `undefined method 'state' for #<ShowFor::Builder:0x007fb669c3c838>` [show_for Dokumentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/show_for#associations) doesn't solve my problem

Comment: If I write `<%= t("activerecord.attributes.ar/state.#{@document.state.name}") %>` outside the show_for I get its translation