# Rails i18n - How to translate enum of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, localization, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got the following model:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum gender: [:female, :male]
  ...
end
```

Then I added the selection of the gender to its form, like this:

```
<%= form_for ([@person]) do |f| %>
  ...
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.collection_radio_buttons :gender, Person.genders, :first, :first %>
  </div>
  ...
<% end %>
```

But instead of displaying the constant as a string I want to translate it to Portuguese.

I already tried to add it to the pt.yml file under people but didn't work.

```
pt:
 activerecord:
   attributes:
     female: Feminino
     male: Mascúlino
```

I know this question is very similar to [How to use i18n with Rails 4 enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827270/how-to-use-i18n-with-rails-4-enums) but that question is already marked as answered and I'm searching for a better and simpler solution...

Thank you for taking your time to help me :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use i18n with Rails 4 enums](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827270/how-to-use-i18n-with-rails-4-enums)

Comment: It's about the same topic but that [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827270/how-to-use-i18n-with-rails-4-enums) is already marked as answered and I'm searching for a better solution...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After reading [How to use i18n with Rails 4 enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827270/how-to-use-i18n-with-rails-4-enums) answers more carefully I came to this solution:

1. According [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models) - *"In the event you need to access nested attributes within a given model, you should nest these under model/attribute at the model level of your translation file"* -

the `yml` file should look like this:

```
pt:
 activerecord:
   attributes:
     person/gender:
       female: Feminino
       male: Mascúlino
```

2. We need to create a method to return a translated `enum` since there isn't any method capable of translating an entire `enum` at once. Rails just has the method to translate a value given a key, i.e People.human_attribute_name("gender.female").

Ok, we'll create a new method but where should we put it?

I think `Helpers` are the best place to put it because I'm changing the enum values in order to easily attach them to the `form collection`, although most of the answers suggested to put it in the `Models`.

Now my `person_helper.rb` looks like this:

```
def human_attribute_genders
  Hash[Person.genders.map { |k,v| [k, Person.human_attribute_name("gender.#{k}")] }]
end
```

And my `view`:

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :gender, human_attribute_genders, :first, :second %>
```

**Pretty simple and it works just fine!**

If anyone has any suggestion to improve my solution I would be happy to hear it from you :)

For example, I could extract the method to `application_helper.rb` like this:

```
def human_attribute_enum(model_name, enum_attr, attr_name)
  Hash[enum_attr.map { |k,v| [k, I18n.t("activerecord.attributes.#{model_name}/#{attr_name}.#{k}")] }]
end
```

But it'd require passing a lot of parameters in the `view`...