# What is the best way to translate enum for use in select with I18n?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, rails-i18n

Is there a better way to write this code?
He currently creates a hash with the translation for its proper enums.

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.translate_enum(enum)
    self.send(enum.to_s).map do |key, value|
      { self.human_enum_name(enum, key) => value }
    end.reduce(:merge)
  end
end

class EnumerableObject < ApplicationRecord
     enum sales_exception: { without: 0, income: 1, commitment: 2, restriction: 3 }, _suffix: true
end

EnumerableObject.translate_enum(:sales_exception)
=> {"Sem Exceção"=>0, "Exceção Renda"=>1, "Exceção Comprometimento"=>2, "Exceção Restrição"=>3}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will prefer to use [enumerate_it](https://github.com/lucascaton/enumerate_it)  gem instead of above, as 
we can define and use [translations](https://github.com/lucascaton/enumerate_it#i18n) with this gem.
Also is simple, provides scopes, helpers methods and easy to reuse enumeration

Comment: Good solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827270/how-to-use-i18n-with-rails-4-enums

Answer (score 0):

[Enumerize](https://github.com/brainspec/enumerize) gem or [Translate Enum](https://github.com/shlima/translate_enum) gem are good options. Both allows you to declare translation in your localization file allowing translation for different languages.
Both are very similar to implement, I've used both, the only reason I would use one over the other is the integration with other gems.

Example for the Translate enum  gem:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include TranslateEnum

  enum status: { published: 0, archive: 1 }
  translate_enum :status
end
```

And in your localization file:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      post:
        status_list:
          published: Was published
          archive: Was archived
```