# Rails enum without underscore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums

I've got Rails 5 app where I'm using enum for `status` column in `User` table like below:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  enum status: {
    approved: 'approved',
    in_review: 'in review'
  }
end
```

When user have `in_review` status it shows me this:

```
2.4.5 :029 > User.first.status
 => "in_review"
```

Which allows me to do:

```
2.4.5 :031 > User.first.in_review?
 => true
```

Is there any way to display `User.first.status` as `in review` without underscore and in addition without losing enum function to get below result?

```
2.4.5 :029 > User.first.status
 => "in review"

2.4.5 :031 > User.first.in_review?
 => true
```

I know I could change the model to:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  enum status: {
    approved: 'approved',
    'in_review': 'in review'
  }
end
```

But then `User.first.in_review?` won't work.

Comment: The enum value is just some internal value and isn't really displayed. Wouldn't it be better to use `I18n` to translate your enum into a human readable name? See [Rails: How to use i18n with Rails 4 enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827270/rails-how-to-use-i18n-with-rails-4-enums)